# AWS Amplify Connect does not return data

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-sdk

I have a very simple GraphQL server, which returns `"Hello World"` if queried with `{ hello }`

I have configured Amplify with the GraphQL endpoint and region and verified that the connection works with this snippet:

```
**THIS IS WORKING**

import {API, graphqlOperation} from 'aws-amplify'

const ListEvents = `query {
  hello
}`

async getNote() {
    try {
      const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(ListEvents))
      console.log(result)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("Unable to fetch hello")
      console.log(e.response)
    }
}

RETURNS:
{
  "data": {
    "hello": "Hello world!"
  }
}
```

**My Problem**

I want to use `Connect` from `aws-amplify-react` as described [HERE](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#connect)

I used the following piece of code and included it in the return of my app:

```
**THIS IS NOT WORKING**

import { Connect } from "aws-amplify-react";

const ListEvents = `query {
  hello
}`

<Connect query={graphqlOperation(ListEvents)}>
    {(obj, ...rest) => {
      console.log(obj);
      console.log(rest);
    }}
</Connect>
```

This RETURNS:

[image: My return of Connect]

The reason for the two empty responses are discussed [in another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607532/aws-amplify-react-connect-returns-undefined-data-first), but this simply never returns the expected data.

**Can you help me figure it out?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax:

```
<Connect query={graphqlOperation(listEvents)}>
    {({ data , loading, error }) => {
        if (error) return (<h3>Error</h3>);
        if (!data) return (<h3>No events found</h3>);
        if (loading) return (<h3>Loading...</h3>);
        return (<h3>{data.hello}</h3> );
    }}
</Connect>
```